# If not Exists problem and possible need for Having clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

Which fields, if any, have never been used for a game or practice?
That is the question I am trying to answer.

I have tried multiple times to get this to work. When I delete the "not exists" portions of the code it returns 5 results. This is correct as there are five Venues where Type = Field. The problem is only two of these 5 Fields are not used in a practice or game.

```
Select Venue.Name, Venue.VenueID 
from Venue 
where Venue.Type = 'Field' 
and not exists (select VenueID from Games) 
and not exists (select VenueID from Practices)
```

The results are based on the data inputted into the database should return two results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very new to MySQL. This looks like it should work for you.
I'm using the `NOT IN` Keyword in place of `NOT EXISTS`

```
Select Venue.Name, Venue.VenueID 
from Venue 
where Venue.Type = 'Field' 
and Venue.VenueID NOT IN (select VenueID from Games) 
and Venue.VenueID NOT IN (select VenueID from Practices)
```

Comment: Thank you! That got it for me!

Comment: If this is working, you should accept this answer @OldTestamentYams ;)

Answer (score 1):

You must set a condition inside the subqueries:

```
Select 
  v.Name, v.VenueID 
from Venue v 
where 
  v.Type = 'Field' 
  and 
  not exists (select VenueID from Games where VenueID = v.VenueID) 
  and 
  not exists (select VenueID from Practices where VenueID = v.VenueID)
```

You want the ids that do not exist in the other 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly discourage you from using `not in` for this purpose.  `NOT IN` will return no rows at all if *any* of the values returned by the subquery is `NULL`.  This is counterintuitive.

When using correlated subqueries, I also strongly recommend qualifying *all* column names.  So I would recommend:

```
select v.Name, v.VenueID 
from Venue v 
where v.Type = 'Field' and
      not exists (select 1 from Games g where g.VenueID = v.VenueID) and
      not exists (select 1 from Practices p where p.VenueID = v.VenueID);
```

Comment: You have bigger problems in you DB if you have NULL ids - I would agree with this answer if it weren't using an ID field.